# How to check the token validity before routing?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, jwt, ngroute

I'm setting up a web application with angularjs routing (ngRoute) and expressjs in the backend.

I have a doubt, **I don´t understand why the "standard" solution to check if user is logged or not is look up for the token in the local storage**. I mean, **its validity is not checked at any time**. It is possible for the user to insert the token manually in the browser.

I am aware that when the user tries to perform an operation **the server side would realize that the user is not logged**, but I think is still possible for a user who inserts manually the token to **access some private routes** (for example, a creation form).

I don´t know how to resolve this problem. **I was trying to ask the server for the validity in the app run**. The problem is that the program does not wait for the promise before routing for the first time.

```
var appRun = function($rootScope, $location, $route, $timeout, API_URL, auth, authToken) {
    //running...
    auth.getProfile();

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
      var routeUrl = '/' + current.replace(API_URL, '').split('/')[1];
      routeUrl = getRouteParams(routeUrl);

      var routeObj = $route.routes[routeUrl];
      var userProfile = authToken.isAuthenticated(), redirectPath;

      //not valid route
      if (!routeObj) {
        redirectPath = getRedirectPath(userProfile);
        $location.path(redirectPath);
      }

      //restricted route
      else if (routeObj.restricted && userProfile !== 'LOGGED') {
        redirectPath = getRedirectPath(userProfile);
        $location.path(redirectPath);
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

```
//In auth service...
 ...

 getProfile: function() {
        if (!(!!authToken.getToken())) { 
            return authToken.setUserProfile('FORBIDDEN') 
        }

        //if the token exists check it
        return $http.get(API_URL + '/auth')
          .then(function(response) {
            authToken.setUserProfile(response.data.status);
            return response;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            return authToken.setUserProfile(error.data.message);
          });
      }

  ...
```

Comment: So what? The hacker won't have access to any sensitive information and won't be able to do any harm by just displaying a form in a browser. And you don't need to display any form to be able to send an HTTP request to a server. What matters is what you're doing at server-side. That's where you must ensure that the request comes from an authenticated user, with a valid token, and who has the permission to execute that request. The token check at client side is just there for ergonomic purposes: you don't want normal users to go to a form that they won't be able to submit successfully anyway.

Comment: You´re right! thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't convert rejected promises

Why do so many examples on Stackoverflow **convert rejected promises** to fulfilled promises?

```
//In auth service...
 ...

 getProfile: function() {
        if (!(!!authToken.getToken())) { 
            ̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶T̶o̶k̶e̶n̶.̶s̶e̶t̶U̶s̶e̶r̶P̶r̶o̶f̶i̶l̶e̶(̶'̶F̶O̶R̶B̶I̶D̶D̶E̶N̶'̶)̶ 
             authToken.setUserProfile('FORBIDDEN') 
             return $q.reject("FORBIDDEN - No token");
        }

        //if the token exists check it
        return $http.get(API_URL + '/auth')
          .then(function(response) {
            authToken.setUserProfile(response.data.status);
            return response;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶T̶o̶k̶e̶n̶.̶s̶e̶t̶U̶s̶e̶r̶P̶r̶o̶f̶i̶l̶e̶(̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶.̶m̶e̶s̶s̶a̶g̶e̶)̶;̶
            authToken.setUserProfile(error.data.message);
            //RE-THROW rejected promises
            throw error;
          });
      }
```

When a promise error handler [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) a value, the $q service **converts** the *rejected* promise to a *fulfilled* promise. To retain the rejected state, either [re-throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) a reason or return a *rejected* promise.

It looks like someone took a function named `getProfile` and hacked it to add side effects. Instead of using the `Profile` promise, they discard the promise and use the side effects.

### Return rejected promise to route resolve function

Functions that return rejected promises can be used in route resolve functions to abort loading a route:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/Book/:bookId', {
        templateUrl: 'book.html',
        controller: 'BookController',
        resolve: {
            profile: function(auth) {
                return auth.getProfile();
            }
        }
    })
})
```

When the `auth.getProfile()` function returns a **rejected promise**, the ngRoute router aborts the load of the view and broadcasts the [$routeChangeError](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#event-$routeChangeError) event.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ngRoute $routeProvider API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)